# The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '6.0.0' (x64) was not found

Tags: docker, .net-6.0

I've recently upgraded from .net5 to .net6 and in my services (not using aspnet), I am getting this error when it tries to start up.

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '6.0.0' (x64) was not found.
  - No frameworks were found.
You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=6.0.0&arch=x64&rid=debian.11-x64
```

This is being deployed using docker and the image is built to use the runtime:6.0 like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS service
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out/service .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyService.dll"]
```

Why is the `runtime:6.0` image having trouble?

Edit:
I've updated my image to use the `aspnet:6.0` image instead to run the service. This fixes it but I'm not sure what is requiring the aspnet image vs the regular runtime image.

Comment: The error says, `The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '6.0.0' (x64) was not found.`. You seem to have configured your application as an ASP.NET Core application in your project files. Can you show us your project files? Your `Main` method?

Comment: It seems that we're using hosted services inside our service project but we've had that in there for a year. So upgrading to .net6 now requires that we use the aspnet image instead of the runtime for some reason. That's mainly what I'm trying to understand

Comment: I have the same problem, except changing to aspnet container did not fix it :( My web based app is working fine, but my hosted worker app is not. The strangest is that the container is complaining it cannot find any frameworks... quite strange

Comment: These are not the framework you're looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using incorrect runtime image - [mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet)
is the one you are looking for:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS service
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out/service .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyService.dll"]
```

**UPD**

> This fixes it but I'm not sure what is requiring the aspnet image vs the regular runtime image.

Check for `Project` tag of .csproj file. If it's `Sdk` attribute is  set to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` then this would be a reason for ASP.NET Core runtime requirement. Also check for libraries [referencing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework) `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`.

**UPD2**

The last suggestion worked - one of the libraries required ASP.NET Core runtime (`MiniProfiler.AspNetCore` in this case) to function correctly.

Comment: Project tag: `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`

Comment: @JoePhillips that's interesting. Do you have an [mre]?

Comment: If I could figure out where the aspnet dependency was coming from, I could make an MRE but of course I'd have solved the problem at that point

Comment: @JoePhillips just a wild guess - are there any libraries [referencing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework) `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` ?

Comment: I think I have a project with a dependency on MiniProfiler.AspNetCore but I've had this for years so I'm not sure why it is all of a sudden a problem unless I upgraded versions and the newer version has that dependency now?

Comment: When I roll back the MiniProfiler version to the old version, I now get errors from my Program.cs because I have AddHostedService() in there. I am perplexed how this ever worked without an aspnet dependency

Comment: @JoePhillips `AddHostedService` per se is not depended on ASP.NET Core - it's part of [`Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.servicecollectionhostedserviceextensions.addhostedservice?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) [nuget which is not depended on ASP.NET Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/7.0.0-preview.5.22301.12#dependencies-body-tab)

Comment: @JoePhillips try removing `MiniProfiler` and add the nuget directly.

Comment: I downgraded MiniProfiler.AspNetCore from 4.2.22 to 4.0.180 and then added `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions` to nuget and that seems to fix my issue somehow

Comment: @JoePhillips so it seems that this is the answer - `MiniProfiler.AspNetCore` in the new version was using some functionality from ASP.NET Core at the startup which was missing the runtime. Though why do you need to add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions` explicitly - I don't know cause it is a dependency for both versions.

Comment: It would be a good idea to update this answer with the findings from the comment (that the real problem is that a dependency itself had a dependency on ASP.NET, which meant the entire application now required the ASP.NET Core runtime).

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel added to the answer for clarity, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Additional info - .net5.0 is now deprecated and incompatible with .net7. If anyone upgrade their web apps from .net5 to .net6 or .net7, they will need to upgrade the hosting components on their web server as well, which can be download from MS site - [ASP.NET Core app to IIS | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-iis?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was a version mismatch.

Ensure your .csproj `PackageReference` tags that use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.xxx` have the same version as your installed runtimes.

I had package references as follows in my csproj:
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="7.0.7" /> <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="7.0.7" PrivateAssets="all" />`

Then when I did `dotnet --list-runtimes` on my command line I found that I have dotnet runtime version 7.0.0 installed:
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]`

I then changed my .csproj packages to point to 7.0.0. Of course, alternatively you can install the version 7.0.7 runtime.

I hope this helps!