# Docker - dotnet no framework found

Tags: docker, ubuntu, .net-core, wsl-2

Trying to run a dotnet core based docker container on a windows 2022 server that's setup with WSL2 (Ubuntu). Running the container fails with the below error message indicating I don't have any dotnet frameworks installed...

```
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: /app/TodoApi.dll
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '6.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: /usr/share/dotnet/

No frameworks were found.
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=6.0.0&arch=x64&rid=debian.11-x64
```

Running `dotnet --info` I can see I have version `sdk - 6.0.400`, `runtime - 6.0.8`

```
azureuser@myworkstation01:/mnt/c/Users/azureuser$ dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   6.0.400
 Commit:    7771abd614

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  20.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.20.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.400/

global.json file:
  Not found

Host:
  Version:      6.0.8
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       55fb7ef977

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.400 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.8 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.8 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Checking in $PATH, i can see there is an environment variable for dotnet already...

```
azureuser@myworkstation01:/mnt/c/Users/azureuser$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Windows/system32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/DockerDesktop/version-bin:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/PowerShell/7/:/mnt/c/Users/azureuser/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/azureuser/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/Users/azureuser/.dotnet/tools:/snap/bin:/home/azureuser/.dotnet/tools
```

I am using WSL2, I can see Docker is configured to use Ubuntu distro in the WSL integration.

[image]

I've config `RollForward` to LatestMajor in my dotnet core project property...

Is there anything obvious I am missing?

Comment: pls share your docker compose file?

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded ubuntu and had the same problem.
Try uninstalling dotnet and specifying the version you want to install.

[Github Reference](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/27082#issuecomment-1211143446)

```
$ sudo apt install aspnetcore-runtime-6.0=6.0.8-1 dotnet-apphost-pack-6.0=6.0.8-1 dotnet-host=6.0.8-1 dotnet-hostfxr-6.0=6.0.8-1 dotnet-runtime-6.0=6.0.8-1 dotnet-sdk-6.0=6.0.400-1 dotnet-targeting-pack-6.0=6.0.8-1
```

Answer (score 0):

The WSL2 led me down a rabbithole. The issue was in the docker file itself, my baseimage didn't have the right aspnet core framework. This has been resolved using the following stackoverflow answer - [The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '6.0.0' (x64) was not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72808225/the-framework-microsoft-aspnetcore-app-version-6-0-0-x64-was-not-found)

Check for Project tag of .csproj file. If it's Sdk attribute is set to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web then this would be a reason for ASP.NET Core runtime requirement. Also check for libraries referencing Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.