# .NET 7 application prompts for both Microsoft.NETCore.App and Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App

Tags: .net, winforms, asp.net-core, .net-7.0

I've created a WinForms application using .NET 7 ("framework-dependent"). After installation to a computer without .NET 7, the user is prompted to first install the Microsoft.NETCore.App framework when first running the application, but when trying to run the application after this they get another prompt to install the Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App framework. The application then runs fine after the second install.

Why are there 2 separate prompts? Some users seem to be getting confused since the prompts look similar and they think they are being asked to install the same thing again.
Is there a way to reduce this to just one prompt?

The application is composed of a single WinForms project: TargetFramework is net7.0-windows

The install files are produced with 'dotnet publish':
-r win-x64 --self-contained false -p:Configuration=Release -p:PublishSingleFile=true -p:Platform=x64

The install is created with InnoSetup. My install doesn't attempt to install .NET 7 - this is left to the default Windows behavior (which prompts twice instead of just once).

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough info at the moment to give a definite answer but here are several possibilities that can in theory result in this behaviour (assuming you have WinForms app):

1. One of the referenced nugets requires the ASP.NET Core runtime ([like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72810186/2501279))
2. The .csproj has `FrameworkReference` element with `Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"` (as can be done to reference ASP.NET Core in library project - [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71320864/what-nuget-packages-must-be-referenced-by-an-asp-net-core-6-application-parts-pr/71321740#71321740))

Comment: No nuget packages and no "Include=".

Comment: @DaveDoknjas then we need a [mre].

Comment: Can't provide my project, but it's easily reproducible: Construct a .NET 7 WinForms project and a simple install using InnoSetup, and then attempt to install and run the application on a machine without .NET 7. You will be blocked twice from running the application with prompts about installing a .NET 7 framework. My point is that there really should just be one prompt which then leads you to install both .NET 7 frameworks.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas just FYI it `FrameworkReference`, not a package reference.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Official page to download .NET 7](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0)
If you only install .NET 7.0 runtime, it may ask you to install the related .NET 7.0 Desktop runtime to support WPF and Windows Forms.
[image]

Comment: My install doesn't install either - the user is prompted separately for each - why wouldn't it just be one prompt for the .NET Desktop Runtime, which includes the other install) ? This wasn't thought out very well.